# How to check for each unique value we have a same unique id in excel

Tags: r, vba, excel, excel-formula

I have a excel sheet which looks like:

```
Col1    Col2
IJ-123  A2B1
IJ-123  A2B1
IJ-456  C2C2
IJ-456  c2c2
IJ-456  D1e2
IJ-789  LJ87
IJ-789  LJ98
```

I want to add one more column and check (for each Unique `Col2` Value) whether the assigned values in `Col1` are `TRUE` or `FALSE`.

So far i have tried this: `=IF(B2=B1,IF(A2=A1,"TRUE","FALSE"))` which is working fine but for every first column of new value in `Col2` it gives me "FALSE" Result.

Output:

```
Col1    Col2  Result
IJ-123  A2B1  TRUE
IJ-123  A2B1  TRUE
IJ-456  C2C2  TRUE
IJ-456  c2c2  TRUE
IJ-456  D1e2  FALSE
IJ-789  LJ87  TRUE (Because Col2 count=1 for this value)
IJ-789  LJ98  TRUE (Because Col2 count=1 for this value)
```

Comment: Is the "Output" what you are expecting to see? or what you currently see? I'm struggling to understand your logic

Comment: @CallumDA Expecting to see...where this line is just for clarification purpose : `(Because Col2 count=1 for this value)`

Comment: So why is D1e2 `FALSE`?

Comment: @CallumDA Because `IJ-456` is assigned to C2C2 if here `Col1` value was other than assigned value than D1e2 should be `TRUE`.

Comment: So by the same logic C2C2 should also be `FALSE`? Since `IJ-456` is also used by `D1e2`?

Comment: @CallumDA No.., here i am checking Value of `Col1` for any same value >1 in `Col2` should have same value in `Col1`.

Comment: @CallumDA But you are right...that should also be wrong or i should get some alert regarding that entries in the data.

Comment: Did my answer not fix your issue?

Comment: @KarlKristjansson No Dear...:(

Comment: So why isn't d1e2 =`True` because col2 count = 1?

Comment: @CallumDA Because it has not unique `Col1` the existing `Col1` value is already mapped to some other `Col2` value which is >1.

Comment: @CallumDA I think its becoming bit complex or i'm not able to clearly communicate the logic. In simple i want to check that for every >1 `Col2` i should have same `Col1` and for every `Col2` value =1 or <1 there should be unique `Col1` value in entire excel sheet.

Comment: @CallumDA it would be great it there could any way through which i can get summarize sheet which give me summary like the `Col1` value for"D1e2" is associated with "C2C2" and vice a versa.

Comment: *"for every Col2 value =1 or <1 there should be unique Col1 value in entire excel sheet."*. If this is the case the LJ87 and LJ89 should be `False`. I think there's some missing logic

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think your logic is actually very complicated, and not explained so well in the initial question -- hence the long discussion in the comments. This is the logic as I now understand it:

> 1. If there are more than 1 of the value in col2, then check that the corresponding col1 values just for those col2 values are the same
> 2. If there is only one of the col2 values then check that the col1 is unique **but only against the col1 values of multiple-occurring col2 values**

Here is the formula:

```
=IF(COUNTIF($B$2:$B$8,B2)=1,SUMPRODUCT(--(($A$2:$A$8=A2)*(COUNTIF($B$2:$B$8,$B$2:$B$8))>1))=0,COUNTIFS($B$2:$B$8,B2,$A$2:$A$8,"<>"&A2)=0)
```

Which returns the following, as required:

[image]

Comment: This works nicely - good job on understanding the requirements :)

Comment: @CallumDA Its working fine but taking hell lot of time to run on 0.15 million rows.

Comment: @CallumDA Do we have any way to run it fast??

Comment: @Roy1245, unfortunately not - it's an expensive operation because every cell needs to check all of the others for uniqueness. How slow is it anyway? You could look into recreating this with VBA which might be a bit faster

Comment: @CallumDA Ohh....:( I'm not good with VBA coding but i think VBA would also work slow. Its working very slow that in ~4 h it only completed 28% Processing and my system got hanged.

Comment: I just tested it with 150,000 rows on my computer and while it is slow, I'm getting through about 1% every 5 seconds -- it should take less than 10minutes! I might give it a go with VBA at some point and see what I can come up with but when you are using that many rows and doing complicated calculations you might want to start looking to transition to SQL

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the false for "b2=b1".

This should fix it:

```
=IF(B2=B1,IF(A2=A1,"TRUE","FALSE"),"FALSE")
```

To simplify, instead of a double if you could use the AND function.

```
If(AND(B2=B1,A2=A1),"True","False")
```